# prove $\int_0^{\pi} \frac{\sin x}{x}$ exists

Tags: calculus

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$, but $\sin x/x$ is not continuous in the closed interval $[0, \pi]$ and does not exist at 0. How do you prove the integral exists, from more fundamental math concepts of the integral? Perhaps it is an argument on the limit of Riemann sums?

Comment: Let $g(0) = 1$ and $g(x) = {\sin x \over x}$ for $x \in (0,1]$. Then $g$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ hence integrable.

Comment: Use the limit definition, and the boundedness of $\sin x$.

Comment: To add to copper.hat answer, the function $g$ and $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ differ at a set of measure 0 and so they will have the same integral if it exists for either of them, which we know it does for $g$.

Comment: It is very easy to establish that the Riemann integrability of a function $f$ on $[a, b]$ does not depend upon the values of $f$ at a finite number of points in $[a, b]$. Hence a finite number of discontinuities in $[a, b]$ does not matter and $f$ is integrable even with finite number of discontinuities. much more than this is true, but needs a bit of measure theory.

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1748621/72031