# If $g$ is bounded and $f=g$, must $g$ be Riemann integrable?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$. If $g$ is bounded and $f=g$ except for finitely many points, must $g$ be a Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$? Give positive proof or a counter example.

I gave a counter example which was not bounded and not a counterexample hence not solved. Please help with this problem.

**counterexample**

Consider $f:[-1,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$, $f(0)=0$ Let $g:[-1,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $g(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ and has a discontinuity at $x=0$ hence does not have measure zero.

Comment: How did you define the Riemann integral? by Darboux sums?

Comment: Your counterexample $g$ isn't bounded.

Comment: The main problem is not that $g$ is not bounded, but that $f$ is not Riemann integrable

Comment: A little bit shorter answer: Lebesgue criterion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose there is $N$ points where $f$ and $g$ are different. If you take an arbitrary subdivision of $[a,b]$, there will be at most $N$ subdivisions with different values.

Let $a_1, \cdots a_N$ be the points where $f$ and $g$ are different, and let's call $d = \min_{i,j} |a_i-a_j|$ the minimal distance between two of such points

Take a partition $a = x_0 < x_1 < \cdots < x_n = b$ with $\delta = \max |x_i-x_{i-1}| <  d/2$, each $a_i$ is contained in a $[x_{n_i-1}, x_{n_{i}}]$, and every interval contain at most one $a_i$

Now, the difference between the upper Darboux sum of $f$ and upper Darboux sum of $g$ is

$$\left| \sum_{k=1}^n (x_{i}-x_{i-1})\sup_{x\in [x_{k-1},x_k]} ( g(x) ) - \sum_{k=1}^n (x_{i}-x_{i-1})\sup_{x\in [x_{k-1},x_k]} ( f(x) ) \right| $$

$$=\left| \sum_{i=1}^N (x_{n_i}-x_{n_i-1})\left( \sup_{x\in [x_{n_i},x_{n_i-1}]} ( g(x) ) - \sup_{x\in [x_{n_i},x_{n_i-1}]} ( f(x) ) \right)\\
+ \sum_{k \neq n_i} (x_{i}-x_{i-1})\left( \underbrace{\sup_{x\in [x_{k-1},x_k]} ( g(x) ) - \sup_{x\in [x_{k-1},x_k]} ( f(x) )}_{=0} \right) \right| $$

$$\leq N \delta \max_i |g(a_i)-f(a_i)|$$

And this converge to $0$ when $\delta \to 0$

The same idea works for lower Darboux sum, and this imply that the lower and upper Darboux sum of $g$ converge : $g$ is integrable (and the integral of $g$ has the same value as the integral of $f$)

By the way, you don't need to assume $g$ bounded : $f$ Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ imply $f$ bounded, and $f$ bounded and $f=g$ except for finitely many points imply $g$ bounded

Answer (score 1):

I think you can solve this with the definition of Riemann integrability via partitions and the difference of upper and lower sums (Riemann's criterion). You can do this by finding a partition P of $[a,b]$ for f where the upper and lower sums 
\begin{align*}U(f,P) - L(f,P) < \frac{\epsilon}{2}
\end{align*}
 Create a finer partition $P^{'}$ where the distance between points directly to the left and right of the discontinuity is of size $\frac{\epsilon}{4Bk}$ where k is the number of discontinuities and where $ \vert g(x) \vert \leq B$ $\forall x \in [a,b]$, which we can do by the boundedness of $g(x)$. While skipping some minor steps that can be added (specifically writing explicitly the definition of $U(f,P)-L(f,P)$, we get that

\begin{align*}
U(g,P^{'}) -L(g,P^{'}) &\leq U(f,P^{'}) - U(f,P^{'}) + \text{ bad points} 
\\
&\text{ (the upper and lower sums are the same besides at these points)}
\\
&\leq U(f,P) - L(f,P) + \text{ bad points}\\
&\text{since }P^{'} \text{ is finer than P}\\
&< \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \text{bad points}\\
&\text{by our hypothesis}\\
&\leq \frac{\epsilon}{2} + k(2B)\frac{\epsilon}{4kB}\\
&\text{where k is the number of bad points}\\
&\text{and 2B is the max distance in any interval from top to bottom of }g\\
&\leq \epsilon \Rightarrow \text{ integrability by Riemann's criterion}
\end{align*}

I really hope the text segments help you understand why everything works.